# Firestore emulator for testing security rules - running the tests

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

I have installed the emulator following the instructions at [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) and I can start it, so far so good.

After picking some code here and there I have written my first test, here it is:

```
import * as firebasetesting from '@firebase/testing';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const projectId = 'my-firebase-project';
const rules = fs.readFileSync('firestore.rules', 'utf8');

beforeAll(async () => {
  // Make your test app load your firestore rules
  await firebasetesting.loadFirestoreRules({ projectId, rules });
});
beforeEach(async () => {
  // Reset our data from our test database
  await firebasetesting.clearFirestoreData({ projectId });
});
after(async () => {
  // Shut down all testing Firestore applications after testing is done.
  await Promise.all(firebasetesting.apps().map(app => app.delete()));
});
describe("TRACKERS AND ALLIES", () => {
  it('TRACKER UP', async () => {
    let user = {username: "Bob", uid: 'bobuid'}
    let target = { username: "Alice", uid: 'aliceuid'}

    const auth = { uid: bob.uid, token: {isadmin: false} };
    const app = firebasetesting.initializeTestApp({ projectId, auth }).firestore();
    const ref = app.doc('users/'+ user.uid + '/contact/' + target.uid);

    await firebasetesting.assertSucceeds(ref.update({ up: true, username: target.uid, timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() }));
  });
})
```

And my question is very simple: how do I run it?

EDIT: I may just add that I am new to Firestore and Javascript in general... The link above simply states

> After running a suite of tests, you can access test coverage reports that show how each of your security rules was evaluated.

So I guess it must be simple, but I cannot find the "run" command anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a nodejs script, run it with `node your-script.js`.  You must have node installed.

If you want to run the script along with the emulator, and shut the emulator down after the script finishes, the page you linked to says:

> In many cases you want to start the emulator, run a test suite, and
>   then shut down the emulator after the tests run. You can do this
>   easily using the emulators:exec command:
>
> ```
> firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "./my-test-script.sh"
> ```

If you found the documentation confusing or incomplete, you should use the "send feedback" button at the top right of the page.

Comment: That got me starting, I get some errors now, wil post a new question if I dont solve them

Comment: So... a lot of things were missing, first of all the code above uses a test framework - which I did not understand at first. I have installed mocha and making progress, however the emulator cannot read the custom claim I have defined in the auth variable, I get an error "Property isadmin is undefined on object"